# What is the best way to clean a stove?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

I have a stainless steel stove that is covered with old oil splatter and other spills. What would be the easiest way to clean it? I would prefer to not use off the shelf cleaning agents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cleaner (*not off the shelf*) is citrus vinegar.

[image: Citrus Vinegar]

It is very simple to make this, the only downside is that it takes 2 weeks of sitting to be completely effective.

> Place citrus peels (any type) in a glass jar (pack fairly tightly) and
>   cover with white vinegar.  Place lid on, and let steep for two weeks. 
>   Strain out peels.
>
> Mix infused vinegar with an equal amount of water
>   and place in a spray bottle to use.

<sup>[*Source*](http://commonsensehome.com/natural-stove-cleaners/)</sup>

---

Another method is to simply use **Baking Soda** & **Table Salt**. What you'll need for this is:

- 1 part table salt
- 1 part baking soda
- 1 part water

Mix them together and apply to the stove top and scrub away.

### If you want something right away

My personal favourite is Straight Lemon Juice, it works wonders when removing the grease. Simply apply it directly to the stove top and scrub off the dirt.
Alternatively, you could use straight vinegar, lemon juice or straight baking soda. They all work well!

Here is a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2q4vCmiIZE) demonstrating using straight baking soda to clean your stove.